# estimate p(z|D) in a VAE

Tags: vae

I have a maybe naive question, but is it easy to estimate p(z|D) for a variational autoencoder where $D = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is an iid training dataset ?
If we write the derivation, we get :
$
p(z|D) = \frac{p(D|z)p(z)}{p(D)} = \frac{p(x_1|z) \dots p(x_n|z)p(z)}{p(x_1 \dots p(x_n))} 
$

and we can use the ELBO of the trained VAE as an approximation for $p(x_i)$ ?
Thanks for your help !